# cancel android countdowntimer on Return key pressed

Tags: android, countdowntimer

My CountDownTimer continue to count even the user press Return key. I put

```
public void onUserLeaveHint(){          
    myTimer.cancel(); 
}
```

and it correctly does myTimer.cancel() timer only when the user press Home key. How can I cancel the timer when the activity where it counts is gone?

Comment: Put the code for cancelling your timer in activity's onPause() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to capture Back key event in Android you will use [`onBackPressed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) like this:

```
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    myTimer.cancel(); 
}
```

Comment: if I put this, I can't go back anymore. the Return key doesn't do anything else then myTimer.cancel();
what have I to add to do standard Return behavior?